# Error on dbase extesion exec php

Tags: php, exec, dbase

When I use exec to use a script

```
exec('nohup php /excel.php  >> /log.log & echo $!', $output);
```

with dbase extension => dbase_open('file.dbf', 0);

php dont reconize dbase extension and return the error

```
Call to undefined function dbase_open()
```

if i use script without exec dbase works well

I think I need load something

Comment: What do you mean "use exec to use a script"? Are you tryin to run a PHP file from another PHP file using `exec()`?

Comment: yes, i edit with line

Comment: Why are you using `exec()` for this? Normally this isn't a good way to call PHP code from other PHP code.

Comment: i do that because is a big script and i execute in a second plan